# Get relative link in view without the HTML tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there a helper like `link_to` that only return the **relative link**? So without HTML tag

From apidock, I only found `url_for` which return **absolute link**.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link_to helper just wraps a given url in an anchor tag. Rails URL helpers do return relative links. Take a look at http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html to get an idea of how to generate your URLs. For example if you setup in your routes file resourceful routes for photos then you can do:

```
photos_path
```

Which would generate /photos

So if you do

```
link_to("Photos", photos_path)
```

It will generate an anchor tag with a relative link to /photos

Comment: Ah thanks for this! Never thought `photos_path` actually is standalone variable

Comment: @DarcCode that's not a variable, that's a method

Comment: @trushkevich Thanks! I'm used to see a method in  `name()` format